# Android Navigation Component clear stack

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I have navigated to a **DialogFragment** from **Navigation drawer** that connected to NavController. But when I navigate to another destination which I have set popUpTo and Inclusive of Dialog fragment it does not clear stack. How can I clear stack?

AM calling this method from LogoutDialog

`findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_logoutDialog_to_auth_navigation)`

Am using fragments and only one activity.

This is part of my navigation graph

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="io.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_auth_navigation"
            app:destination="@id/auth_navigation"
            app:popUpTo="@id/homeFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
        <argument
            android:name="fromLogin"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
    </fragment>

    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/logoutDialog"
        android:name="io.ui.dialog.LogoutDialog"
        android:label="LogoutDialog" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_logoutDialog_to_auth_navigation"
            app:destination="@id/auth_navigation"
            app:popUpTo="@id/logoutDialog"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </dialog>

    <!-- auth navigation graph -->
    <navigation
        android:id="@+id/auth_navigation"
        app:startDestination="@id/loginFragment">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
            android:name="io.ui.login.LoginFragment"
            android:label="fragment_login"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login">
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_OTPFragment"
                app:destination="@id/OTPFragment"
                app:popUpTo="@id/loginFragment"
                app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_homeFragment"
                app:destination="@id/homeFragment" />
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_resetPasswordFragment"
                app:destination="@id/resetPasswordFragment" />
        </fragment>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/OTPFragment"
            android:name="io.ui.login.OTPFragment"
            android:label="fragment_otp"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_otp">
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_OTPFragment_to_homeFragment"
                app:destination="@id/homeFragment"
                app:popUpTo="@id/OTPFragment"
                app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_OTPFragment_to_loginFragment"
                app:destination="@id/loginFragment"
                app:popUpTo="@id/OTPFragment"
                app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/resetPasswordFragment"
            android:name="io.ui.profile.PasswordFragment"
            android:label="fragment_reset_password"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_password" >
            <argument
                android:name="isReset"
                app:argType="boolean"
                android:defaultValue="false" />
        </fragment>

    </navigation>
```

Answer (score 14):

You're a looking for these attribute to put in your action.

- The `popUpTo` attribute of an action "pops up" the back stack to a given destination before navigating. (Destinations are removed from the back stack.)
- If the `popUpToInclusive` attribute is false or is not set, `popUpTo` removes destinations up to the specified destination, but leaves the specified destination in the back stack.
- If `popUpToInclusive` is set to true, the `popUpTo` attribute removes all destinations up to and including the given destination from the back stack.
- If `popUpToInclusive` is true and `popUpTo` is set to the app's starting location, the action removes all app destinations from the back stack. The Back button takes the user all the way out of the app.

---

EDIT: ALSO I'm adding this really great video which explains it with example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mLfWvSGG5c8

Comment: I have set popUpTo to the layouDialog and popUpToInclusive to true but when I navigate from dialog fragment it does not clear stack

Comment: Could you add your nav_graph and how you handle it ?

Comment: I have added the navigation graph

Comment: Could you take a look at [popBackStack](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController.html#popBackStack(int,%20boolean)) and try this out

Comment: Had also tried this, but it would work first time, but any consecutive logout had a similar problem as above

Comment: Can you try poping the whole graph with : `app:popUpTo="@id/nav_graph"` ?

Comment: @Biscuit thanks for `app:popUpTo="@id/nav_graph"`. It's very good solution when you need to redirect to login fragment when session is expired and clear backstack completely

Comment: @Biscuit asked about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68586929/how-can-i-clear-every-fragments-in-back-stack-using-navigation-component-for-ex