# How can I clear every fragments in back stack using Navigation Component (for example when HTTP 401 triggeres) and sent to login fragment

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

We have next attributes to remove fragment/fragments when opening another one.

```
app:popUpTo="..."
app:popUpToInclusive="true"
```

But in case when I need to clear all back stack not knowing which id was the first one (and start destination could have been already removed from stack) on 401 events for example.

How can I do it?

For example I may have 5 fragments in back stack and I don't know the id of the first one, and how can I remove them all and open a login fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

We can use `R.id.nav_graph` (id of our Navigation Graph) for `setPopUpTo()` to clear backstack completely

```
val navOptions = NavOptions.Builder()
    .setPopUpTo(R.id.nav_graph, true)
    .build()
navController.navigate(R.id.loginFragment, null, navOptions)
```

**Previous answer:**

I implemented this solution, though it looks difficult

```
navController.graph = navController.graph.apply {
    startDestination = R.id.loginFragment
}
val navOptions = NavOptions.Builder()
    .setPopUpTo(R.id.loginFragment, true)
    .build()
navController.navigate(R.id.loginFragment, null, navOptions)
```

But it works and clears all back stack and only one loginFragment will be in the stack