# How to prevent to reopen fragment in Main fragmet of BottomNavigation?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-navigation

I have 5 `item` in `BottomNavigationBar` inside `MainActivity` class. When open `EarningFragment` it has `FragmentContairView` and it open `MoneyDetailFragment` from `EarningFragment`. When I opened this `MoneyDetailFragment` it opened.

In the scenario when click another item on `BottomNavigationBar` and click again item for `EarningFragment` it rememeber that was in `MoneyDetailFragment` and it opened this class. I don't want it is remember where it was. I want it open only `EarningFragment` when click it in `BottomNavigationBar`. That's so complicated hope you can understand it.

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener,
                     View.OnClickListener {
private lateinit var navHostFragment: NavHostFragment

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
 navHostFragment.navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(this)
}
     private fun setupBottomNavigationView() {
     BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(binding.bottomBar.bottomNavViewBar)
     binding.bottomBar.bottomNavViewBar.setupWithNavController(navHostFragment.navController)
        }
}
```

nav_graph_main.xml

```
    <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/nav_graph_main"
        app:startDestination="@id/miHome">
    
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/miHome"
            android:name="com.mi.ui.home.HomeFragment"
            android:label="@string/menu_home"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_to_earningFragment"
                app:destination="@id/miEarnings" />
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_to_moneyGoldRegisterFragment"
                app:destination="@id/moneyGoldRegisterFragment" />
</fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/miEarnings"
        android:name="com.mi.ui.earning.EarningFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_bottom_earnings"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_earning">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_to_moneyCardFragment"
            app:destination="@id/moneyCardFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_to_moneyDetailFragment"
            app:destination="@id/moneyDetailFragment" />
    </fragment>
```

Comment: Hard to follow your problem, but have a look at this question and the answers given: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50514758/how-to-clear-navigation-stack-after-navigating-to-another-fragment-in-android This may help you to figure out a solution.

Comment: Or look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60739262/android-navigation-component-clear-stack

Comment: But I'm pretty sure that the standard behaviour for bottom navigation means that you can switch between the views in the bottom nav bar and each view contains its own state and back stack. This is what the user would expect. So maybe you have an architectural confusion.

Comment: Yeah. I think that user this expected. I don't know why this user want this.:D

Comment: You should accept your answer as it will remove the question from the list of unanswered questions and may help someone else with a similar problem.

Comment: @DavidWasser ok I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DavidWasser thank you so much. The user as "Biscuit" named in the second link that I solved from it. I added these code to MainActivity to clear state of navigation that I want to open.

```
 binding.bottomBar.bottomNavViewBar.setOnItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.miHome -> {
                    navHostFragment.navController.navigate(R.id.miHome)
                    true
                }
                R.id.miBarcode -> {
                    navHostFragment.navController.navigate(
                        R.id.miBarcode,
                        null,
                        NavOptions.Builder()
                            .setPopUpTo(R.id.miBarcode, true)
                            .build())
                    true
                }
                R.id.miEarnings -> {
                    navHostFragment.navController.navigate(
                        R.id.miEarnings,
                        null,
                        NavOptions.Builder()
                            .setPopUpTo(R.id.miEarnings, true)
                            .build())
                    true
                }
                R.id.miProfil -> {
                    navHostFragment.navController.navigate(
                        R.id.miProfil,
                        null,
                        NavOptions.Builder()
                            .setPopUpTo(R.id.miProfil, true)
                            .build())
                    true
                }
                else -> {
                    navHostFragment.navController.navigate(R.id.miHome)
                    true
                }
            }
        }
```